# combining p values as pair?

Tags: r, p-value

I have a data:

```
controls    cases
0.7433018893    0.5258425596
0.6592615656    0.4859544482
0.3695427609    0.3641427198
0.0508736108    0.171792228
0.6630316215    0.5950126248
0.4571880027    0.8807510188
0.0469831145    0.7860116142
```

I want to combine the p value of controls (e.g., 0.7433018893) with its corresponding / pair / p value of cases (e.g., 0.5258425596).

Required output:

```
controls    cases Combine_p_value 
0.7433018893    0.5258425596 xxxxxxxx
0.6592615656    0.4859544482 xxxxxxxx
```

I am using R package `metamp` with the following code:

```
x <- c(0.7433018893,0.5258425596)
sumlog(x)
chisq =  1.878813  with df =  4  p =  0.7580359
```

How to automate this process in R? There are methods available if you have a list pf p values but here we have list of paired p values? Any help appreciated....,,,!!!!

Waqas.

Comment: Try `apply(DF[,c("controls", "cases")], 1, function(x) sumlog(x))`

Comment: Yes d.b , this command worked for me, thats great, Thanks